# Strip tags with javascript and handle line breaks

Tags: javascript, sanitization, strip-tags

I want to strip tags from a html, but preserves it's line breaks.

I want the behaviour like copying the text in browser and pasting it in notepad.

For example, a code that converts:

- `<div>x1</div><div>x2</div>` to `x1\nx2`
- `<p>x1</p><p>x2</p>` to `x1\nx2`
- `<b>x1</b><i>x2</i>` to `x1x2`
- `x1<br>x2` to `x1\nx2`

Removing all tags not works (/<.*?>/g).
Also creating a dummy <div> and settings it's `innertHTML` and read it's `textContent` will remove line breaks.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function strip_tags(str){
    return str
             .replace(/(<(br[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
             .replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
}

var str = '<div>x1</div><div>x2</div><br>'+'<p>x1</p><p>x2</p>'+'<b>x1</b><i>x2</i>';
```

This will strip the tags and replace `<br />` or `<br>` with new lines, but adding new lines for block elements requires quite some time to come up with a solution.

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/P39NH/)

Answer (score 3):

How's this work for you?  This will replace every occurrence of `<br>`, `</div>`, and `</p>` with a `\n`, and then strip the remaining tags.  Its goofy, but its at least a start.

```
fixed = text_to_fix.replace(/<(?:br|\/div|\/p)>/g, "\n")
           .replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
```

This doesn't work for all HTML, however.  Just the tags you mentioned.

Comment: div, p and br are just examples of many tags that causes line break (hr, li, tr, ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I got before I got bored...

```js
const strip_tags = (html) => {
    let tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.innerHTML = html
        .replace(/(<(br[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(p[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(div[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(h[1-6][^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(li[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(ul[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(ol[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(blockquote[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(pre[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(hr[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(table[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(tr[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(td[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(th[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(caption[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(dl[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(dt[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(dd[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(address[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(section[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(article[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n')
        .replace(/(<(aside[^>]*)>)/ig, '\n');
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function stripTags(html) {
     return html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/<\/[^>]+>/g, '\n').replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
}
```

Now the function will replace all opening and closing tags with nothing, and `<br>` tags with line breaks. This should give you the desired output.